# Trying to pass parameters to a jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, parameters

so i have my original ajax call which works fine.

```
$.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "index.php / blog / getbio",
            data: { first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name button_type:button_type },
            success: function (msg) {
                $(button).text(msg);
                button.slideDown("slow");
            }

        });
```

I'm trying to create a function so that I dont have to retype this every time and all i want to modify is the data and url fields of the ajax call. Though I don't know exactly how to replacte the data field outside of the ajax call. I've gotten as far as

```
var params = "first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name";
var url = "index.php / blog / getbio";
function ajax(url, params) {
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: { params },
            success: function (msg) {
                $(button).text(msg);
                button.slideDown("slow");
            }

        });
        button.hide();
    }
```

Though I know this doesn't work. SO my question is  outside of the ajax function how can i  have the variable params be properly created to nicely be inserted inside the ajax function.

Comment: Try to use Global variable
for example:
window.url="index.php/blog/getbio";       //global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set data in json format for putting it into a string more easily:

```
var params = '{"first_name": "first_name", "last_name": "last_name"}';
var url = "index.php/blog/getbio";
$.ajax({
url: url,
data: params, 
dataType:'json', 
success: function (msg) {
            $(button).text(msg);
            button.slideDown("slow");
        }
 });
```

Comment: would it be data:data or data:params?

Comment: Do you have everything in Double quotes becuase of the underlines?

Comment: If you mean params string, double quotes are needed for making valid json format.

Comment: Well i'm getting a disallowed key characters but thats a codeigniter error so at least the ajax request is being sent. Fixing that error is for another question for another day.

Answer (score 0):

```
function CreateFullName(f_name, l_name) {
    params = {
        "first_name": f_name, 
        "last_name": l_name
    };  
    return params;
}

function ajax(url, first_name, last_name) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: CreateFullName(first_name, last_name),
            success: function (msg) {
                $(button).text(msg);
                button.slideDown("slow");
            }

        });
        button.hide();
    }
```

here the function is not bound with any hard coded value, use this generally with url and name values passed.